# Print a 2D string

Tags: arrays, c, string, multidimensional-array, 2d

complete beginner here. I'm trying to print the elements of a 2d spring like this:

O O O

O O O

O O O

But my program's output looks like this:

OOOOOOOOO

OOOOOO

OOO

Can someone help me please?

```
int main(void) 
{
  int k;

  char game[3][3] = {
                    "OOO",
                    "OOO",
                    "OOO",
                    }; 

    for (k = 0; k < 3 ; k++) 
{
    printf("%s", game[k]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Edit:

I did this and it works now

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
      printf("%c ", game[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
```

Comment: How many bytes do you need to store the string `"000"`? Hint: it is not 3.

Comment: Why isn't it 3? There are 3 characters in each row

Comment: Alright, I found a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
const char *game[3][3] = { {"O", "O", "O"}, {"O", "O", "O"}, {"O", "O", "O"} };
```

this is how a 2d array looks like

Comment: Character literals and strings are not the same. `"0"` should be `'0'`